# Using margins with vce(unconditional) option after xtreg

Tags: stata

I am using Stata 13 and I have a balanced panel dataset (`t=Year` and `i=Individual` denoted by `Year` and `IndvID` respectively) and the following econometric model

```
 Y = b1*var1 + b2*var2 + b3*var1*var2 + b4*var4 + fe + epsilon
```

am estimating the following fixed-effects regression with year dummies and a linear time trend

```
 xi: xtreg Y var1 var2 c.var1#c.var2 var3 i.Year i.IndvID|Year, fe vce(cluster IndvID)
```

(all variables are continuous except for dummies being created by `i.Year` and `i.IndvID|Year`)

I want Stata to derive/report the overall marginal effect of `var1` and `var2` on the outcome `Y`:

```
 dY/dvar1 = b1 + b3*var2

 dY/dvar2 = b2 + b3*var1
```

Because I estimate the fixed-effect regression using robust standard errors, I want to make sure the marginal effect are being computed taking into account the same heterogeneity that the clustered standard errors correct for. My understanding is that this can be achieved using the
`vce(unconditional)` option of the margins command. However, after running the above regression, when I run the command

```
 margins, dydx(var1) vce(unconditional)
```

I get the following error:

```
 xtreg is not supported by margins with the vce(unconditional) option
```

Am I missing something obvious here or am I not going about this correctly? How can I cluster standard errors for margin estimates computed for Stata rather than using the Delta Method default, which doesn't correct for this?

Thanks in advance,

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

The marginal effect of `var1` and `var2` are functions (of `var1` and `var2`, respectively).  If you want the marginal effect of `var1` at the mean level of `var2`, for example, you can use the `lincom` command after the regression:

```
sum var2
local m1 = r(mean)
lincom var1 + `m1' * c.var1#c.var2
```

This calculates the point estimate of the marginal effect at the mean as well as the standard errors derived from the robust covariance matrix estimated in `xtreg`.